# DAX Filtering Logic For Each Value of a Dimension

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In DAX - what is the most efficient way to produce the desired output:

[image]

I want to say this would be similar to a correlated subquery in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **OPTION-1**

**Step-1:** Create a **Custom Column** as below-

```
is_min_date = 

// -- keep current row's customer id to a variable
VAR current_cust_id = store[Customer ID]
// -- keep current row's YEAR value to a variable
VAR current_date = store[Order Date]

// -- find the MIN YEAR from order date for the current row customer id
VAR min_date_current_custommer_id =  
CALCULATE(
    MIN(store[Order Date]),
    FILTER(
       store,
        store[Customer ID] = current_cust_id
    )
)

// -- check the current row's year is the MIN year of order date for the customer as well or not.
RETURN IF(current_date = min_date_current_custommer_id, 1,0)
```

**Step-2:** Now add a basic filter in your visual as below and you will get your desired rows your table visual-

[image]

> **OPTION 2:**
> The same can be achieved using Measure as well instead of creating a Custom Column. Just do this below-

**Step-1:** Create the measure as below-

```
is_min_date_measure = 

VAR min_order_date_for_current_customer = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN(store[Order Date]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(store),
        store[Customer ID] = MIN(store[Customer ID])
    )
)

RETURN
IF ( MIN(store[Order Date]) = min_order_date_for_current_customer, 1,0)
```

**Step-2:** Now add visual level filter as below and you will get you desired output-

[image]